# Background image height 100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to centre a background image in a div, I put it into another div and centred it from there, but because I want the height to be 100% it doesn't show. I have tried to add float:left; but then the div doesn't centre even if I set the left and right margins to Auto.

How can I make a background image to 100% ?

Comment: To position a background image... `background-position: center center;`. To make sure the background covers the whole height of its container... `background-size: auto 100%;`

Comment: Your question isn't specific. I see you found a solution that satisfies you but if you want to help others with your question, you should specify it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this and it seem to work great.

```
margin:0px auto 0 auto; position:relative;
min-height: 100%; /* min. height for modern browser */
height:auto !important; /* important rule for modern Browser */
height:100%; /* min. height for IE */
overflow: hidden !important; /* FF scroll-bar */
background:url(../images/con-background.gif) 0 0 repeat-y; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For modern browsers you could just use:

```
background-size: cover;
```